# MySQL Find Full Name Across Two Rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where I'm trying to find a person by his full name.  The problem is that first and last name are stored on two separate rows in the table as shown here:

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| submit_time     | form_name   | field_name  | field_value  |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1323463601.0947 | Online Form | firstname   | Paulo        |
| 1323463601.0947 | Online Form | lastname    | Hill         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

How can I construct a query that will get a single result (if possible) by searching for Paulo Hill?

Also, the submit_time column should have the same value for both rows--that will be the one column value that is unique in the table.

Comment: Looks like an EAV data model except that I don't see any Entity ID to link the two rows together. Are these all the columns?

Comment: If `submit_time` is the same in each row, how can it possibly be unique in the table?  And are you sure two forms can't be sumitted at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.submit_time, t1.field_value, t2.field_value
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON t2.submit_time = t1.submit_time
WHERE t1.field_name = 'firstname'
AND t1.field_value = 'Paulo'
AND t2.field_name = 'lastname'
AND t2.field_value = 'Hill'
```

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz 'Paulo Hill' is the search term. ...What do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing `'paulo hill'` is a single search query:

```
    SELECT t1.*,
           t2.field_value
      FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.submit_time = t2.submit_time
       AND t2.field_name = 'lastname'
     WHERE t1.field_name = 'firstname'
       AND t1.field_value || ' ' || t2.field_value = 'paulo hill'
```

Note: this solution is sensitive to amount of spaces between first name and last name in search query

Comment: Your first query would find "Paulo Hill", but since you're not restricting the field_name it could also get false positives, like somebody named "Jonah Hill" with a dog named "Paulo", or somebody named "Paulo Smith" who lives on a "hill", etc.

Comment: @Ike Walker: yep, remove it then, since it is not an answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT submit_time, group_concat(field_value SEPARATOR  ' ')  AS fullname
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  GROUP BY `submit_time`
) AS innertable
WHERE fullname='Paulo Hill'
```

Comment: `group by` doesn't define order for other columns

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) if you know the order:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_value SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM tab
GROUP BY submit_time
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(field_value ORDER BY field_id ASC) LIKE '%Paulo,Hill%'
```

Comment: `group by` doesn't define order for other columns